# How To Get YEARWEEK() To See Sunday As The Start Of The Week?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the YEARWEEK function to see Sunday as the 1st day of the week.

An example date is: Sunday 1st Mar 2009

Here is my sql

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2009-03-01')
```

and the result is

-> 200909

Which is week 9. I believe it is telling me this is week 9 because it sees the sunday as the last day of the previous week.

How would I get this function to see sunday as the 1st day of the week and therefore return as week 10?

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-03-01', '%Y%U')` also returns `200909` - I think your belief about it being 200910 is incorrect: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 5):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek, `YEARWEEK` has an optional second argument which controls this. `YEARWEEK('2009-03-01', 0)` should do what you want (but see the table of possible values under `WEEK` on that page).

Answer (score 1):

this will do it:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2009-03-01')+IF(WEEKDAY('2009-03-01')=6,1,0);
```

**EDIT:** this is the better solution, for more information click [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week):

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2009-03-01',0);
```

(but i don't know why you want to do this - 2009.03.01 *is* in week 9, not 10...)