# Want to show weekly highest scorer details grouped by month

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table of data:

```
id   |   name   |  userid  |  score   |      date      |
--------------------------------------------------------
 1   |   john   |    4     |   233    |  2014-02-02 
 2   |   mary   |    5     |   1256   |  2013-02-05  
 3   |   john   |    6     |   100    |  2013-03-08 
 4   |   elvis  |    7     |   123    |  2013-03-04 
 5   |   john   |    2     |   1234   |  2013-03-02
```

I want to show the weekly high score details of last month.week start from Sunday. every week show maximum 4 highest scorer.My data will be output in json format.

Currently my query output shows only the last  week result.

```
"weekly_winners":[
    {
        "id":"2",
        "score":"1256"
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "score":"233"
    }
],
```

But I want to show look like

```
"weekly_winners":[
    "week":"1"
        [
            {
                "id":"2",
                "score":"1256"
             },
             {
                "id":"1",
                "score":"233"
             }
        ],
    "week":"2"
        [
            {
                "id":"2",
                "score":"1256"
             },
             {
                "id":"1",
                "score":"233"
             }
        ],
],
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT winner.id,winner.score
FROM `winner` AS  winner
WHERE winner.date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
    AND winner.date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY 
ORDER BY winner.score DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the grouping with the `YEARWEEK()` command. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004914/1803682) on making Sunday the beginning of the week.

So you can use: `YEARWEEK(winner.date, 0)` to specify the week.

As for selecting the top N rows by group, the best reference I have found on the doing this is [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/). Scroll down to the section:

> Select the top N rows from each group

I have used this article to solve this exact problem in the past.

*Note: `YEARWEEK()` will handle the new year by putting all dates up to the day specified to begin a new week into the last week of the previous year... as you would / should expect.

**EDIT:**

Here is a possible Query (selects top two to avoid a bunch of data entry for the fiddle example):

```
SELECT winner.id,winner.score, YEARWEEK(winner.date, 0)
FROM `winner` AS  winner
WHERE (
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM winner as w
  WHERE YEARWEEK(w.date, 0) = YEARWEEK(winner.date, 0) 
        AND w.score >= winner.score
) <= 2;
```

[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ea72/3)

Comment: can you give me example query

Comment: Try that - should start to approach what you need / get you close enough to complete it. Add more data and play. Small change to pick highest two, not lowest.